# Free software for tutoring remotely?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, tablet

I'm going to start live tutoring remotely for some extra cash. I own a tablet with stylus, but am considering getting a Wacom Bamboo for my desktop because I'm not sure my tablet could handle recording/streaming.

What type of software would be good for sharing what I'm writing and communicating simultaneously?

- should run on Windows
- support writing and voice
- it will be 1-on-one tutoring
- similar to Khan academy but live

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with any combination of a whiteboard and screensharing softwares.

For the first part, I recommend [**OneNote**](http://www.onenote.com/), mainly because it has a wide array of drawing and annotating tools, along with pretty accurate handwriting recognition. It can also recognize equations written by hand. I use it with my Bamboo pad, and it's very responsive. You can also share the notebook with the student who will be able to save it or print it for later reviewing. It...

- Runs on Windows, the web, and other platforms
- Supports freehand writing
- Supports collaboration

For the screen sharing aspect, I think [**Google Hangouts**](https://hangouts.google.com/) is one of the simplest ways. After initiating a voice call, you can start screen sharing. It allows you to either share the entire screen or just a single window, in this case, the OneNote window.

[**Skype**](http://www.skype.com/en/) and [**TeamViewer**](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/index.aspx) are two other examples you could use for screen sharing. TeamViewer also has a built in whiteboard, but I find it lacking in several basic features, like saving your work.

Comment: Figured simple, familiar software would end up being the best bet. Thanks for elaborating.